# What does third 'for' mean in #define for for(int z=0;z<2;++z)for

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have found a piece of code in a C++ program, it seems that it loops two times every `for()` loop in this program, but why does it need this third for in such preprocessor definition?

`#define for for(int z=0;z<2;++z)for`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It replaces `for` with `for(int z=0;z<2;++z)for`. Obviously, that would turn

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

into

```
for (int z=0;z<2;++z) for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

Thus creating two nested loops. Without that extra `for` it would be

```
for (int z=0;z<2;++z) (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

Which is obviously incorrect.

Note that even though it's “correct” in the form you gave in your question, it doesn't mean it's a “good practice”. This is an example of excessive macro abuse and *must* be avoided. Here is one of the numerous examples how it could go wrong:

```
for (int z = 0; z < 5; ++z) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << z << std::endl; // this will never print 2, 3, 4
    }
}
```

This will expand into

```
for (int z=0;z<2;++z) for (int z = 0; z < 5; ++z) {
    for (int z=0;z<2;++z) for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << z << std::endl; // this will never print 2, 3, 4
    }
}
```

Meaning that you now have *four* nested loops, and that the inner loop will print the “invisible” `z` instead of the `z` you have declared in the outer loop (which becomes the second-level loop in the expanded code).

Another reason: as pointed by @stefan, it's a very bad idea to use keywords or other well-known identifiers as macro names. Makes one think of the infamous `#define true false`. And, as @HolyBlackCat mentions, it's also undefined behavior, meaning that as far as the standard is concerned, *anything* could happen. Ranging from the code “seemingly working” to a full-blown World War III with Martians (who invaded Earth to cleanse it from ugly code).

Comment: Thank you for the "must be avoided" part.

Comment: Thanks! And these examples are great! And instead of this third for, would it be possible to make it work with while loop? Like `#define for for(int z=0;z<2;++z)while` ?

Comment: It must be avoided also as `for` is a keyword. Unless this is an exam the inventor should be hunted down and ...

Comment: @Hbo-ot, you can do all sorts of evil things with macros. The preprocessor doesn't really care whether it's `for`, `while`, or `killMePleaseForWritingThisCode`. Substitute yourself one for another and see what you get. That's exactly what the compiler will see. Unless, of course, your macro expands to another macro, thus dooming anyone who tries to understand that mess unless he's a level 80 legacy code porter.

Comment: AFAIK, not only this is a crappy practice, but applying `#define` to a keyword is also UB.

Comment: Are you sure double z would not compile?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov, well, I will experiment on this, thanks for explaining on how it works.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, really? I had no idea, but it seems you're right.

Comment: @Slava, I was 100% sure it won't, but now that I've tried it—it really does! I've just learned two new things!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that macro is the ugliest thing I've ever seen. I don't recommend ever doing something like this.

The top answer from Sergey Tachenov is really great, but it should also be mentioned that this macro really makes **every** for loop run twice. This means the doubly nested loops shown below will execute 400 times (not 200 times)! This might be unexpected.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // I'll be executed 100 times without the macro
    }
}
```

becomes

```
for (int z=0;z<2;++z) for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int z=0;z<2;++z) for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // I'll be executed 400 times with the macro
    }
}
```

It only gets worse from here. Consider an infinte loop like

```
int some_condition = 0;
for(;;) {
    // insert logic here for calculating whether to break out
    if (some_condition) {
        some_condition = 0; // set back to false for use down the line
        break;
    }
}
```

turns into

```
int some_condition = 0;
for (int z=0;z<2;++z) for (;;) {
    // insert logic here for calculating whether to break out
    if (some_condition) {
        some_condition = 0; // set back to false for use down the line
        break; // gets me out of for(;;)...but the outer loop repeats
    }
}
```

which bumps you out of the inner infinite loop if the condition is met....only to go right back in it. Now you might be stuck in an infinite loop.

Unexpected behavior is a good reason to avoid something, and macro shenanigans like this is very dangerous, and could be a real b**ch to debug. Imagine if some include directive had this ported in several header files deep...

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor substitution occurs in a single pass and does not support recursion.  So the second "for" is probably for some zany idea of chaining existing "for" loops, prepending them with the macro "for" loop portion.

```
#define for for(int z=0;z<2;++z)for
```

Thus it replaces

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
     // ...
}
```

with

```
for(int z=0;z<2;++z)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
       // ...
    }
```

Which is a pretty crazy use of the preprocessor.